# String to NSDecimalNumber Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdecimalnumber

Can someone confirm for me this is the correct way to convert a `NSString` to an `NSDecimalNumber`? I have a label where when you click the button the price shows up, which is called `totalPriceCalculated` and then I also have all the strings where the calculations are made. Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)calculateTotalPrice:(id)sender {
    NSString *priceStringOne = [hiddenPriceOneTF text];
    float priceFloatOne = [priceStringOne NSNumberFormatter];

    NSString *priceStringTwo = [hiddenPriceTwoTF text];
    float priceFloatTwo = [priceStringTwo floatValue];

    NSString *priceStringThree = [hiddenPriceThreeTF text];
    float priceFloatThree = [priceStringThree floatValue];

    NSString *priceStringFour = [hiddenPriceFourTF text];
    float priceFloatFour = [priceStringFour floatValue];

    NSString *quanityStringOne = [quanityFirstTF text];
    float quanityFloatOne = [quanityStringOne floatValue];

    NSString *quanityStringTwo = [quanitySecondTF text];
    float quanityFloatTwo = [quanityStringTwo floatValue];

    NSString *quanityStringThree = [quanityThirdTF text];
    float quanityFloatThree = [quanityStringThree floatValue];

    NSString *quanityStringFour = [quanityFourthTF text];
    float quanityFloatFour = [quanityStringFour floatValue];

    float totalAmount = priceFloatOne * quanityFloatOne + priceFloatTwo * quanityFloatTwo + priceFloatThree * quanityFloatThree + priceFloatFour * quanityFloatFour ;
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" $ %0.2f", totalAmount];

    [totalPriceCalculated setText:result];

    NSString *totalPrice = totalPriceCalculated.text;
    NSDecimalNumber *totalPriceNumber = (NSDecimalNumber *)totalPrice;
}

NSString *priceStringOne = [hiddenPriceOneTF text];

float priceFloatOne = [priceStringOne NSNumberFormatter];
```

***UPDATED****

```
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:totalPriceNumber];
payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
payment.shortDescription = @"Hipster t-shirt";
```

Comment: You cannot convert an object from one class to another with a cast.

Comment: BTW - converting from the string won't work due to the leading `$`.

Comment: Also, don't use `stringWithFormat:` to convert a decimal value to a string for display to the user. Instead, use an `NSNumberFormatter`. This will ensure the value is formatted properly for the user's locale. And also, don't use `floatValue` to convert the user entered numbers. Again, use an `NSNumberFormatter` to parse the text to a `float`. This allows a user to enter their numbers in a familiar format for their locale.

Comment: I have tried to update this but I get an error saying "No Visible @interface for NSString declares the selector NSNumberFormater".

Am I forgetting something. If I am reading your comments right this is what i have

    NSString *priceStringOne = [hiddenPriceOneTF text];
    
    float priceFloatOne = [priceStringOne NSNumberFormatter];

 Also added to above code so easier to read

Comment: Your attempt at using an `NSNumberFormatter` isn't even close to correct. Do some searching on using `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to create the decimal number from the `float`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *totalPriceNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[@(totalAmount) decimalValue]];
```

Comment: I tried this way but when I add the totalPriceNumber to where i want the value inserted it, it still gives me an error saying incompatible pointer types sending NSDecimalNumber to parameter of type NSString.  I updated the above code to show where i want to place the totalPriceNumber. (its into PayPal iOS code)

Comment: Look at what you are trying to do. `totalPriceNumber` is already an `NSDecimalNumber` and you are treating it as an `NSString` and needlessly trying to create another `NSDecimalNumber`. Just do: `payment.amount = totalPriceNumber;`.

Comment: Awesome Thanks! I just started to learn iOS coding, so I don't know anything about the NSDecimalNumber. So I will go do some searching on the NSNumberFormater. Thanks

Comment: I would urge you to take a step back for a bit and find some good tutorials on the Objective-C programming language and the basics of programming. Learning the basics now will save you a lot of time fighting issues like this. Your issue here isn't a lack of understanding of a class like `NSDecimalNumber`, it's a lack of understanding of basic programming knowledge. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`totalPriceNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:totalAmount];`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html), the prefered way is to use [+decimalNumberWithString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString%3a); hope that helps.